# htmleditorextender does not display toolbar

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working on Asp.Net 4.5 on visual studio2012. I had an ajaxcontrolkit htmleditorextender which has targetId bind on asp, textbox. However i did everything in the asp.net tutorial but i could not succeed on displaying the toolbar.

I have checked page register, toolkitscriptmanager. Still it's the same. Any ideas?
And here is my code:

```
     <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>
```

```
    <asp:TextBox
    ID="txtComments"
    TextMode="MultiLine"
    Columns="60"
    Rows="8"
    runat="server" />

    <asp:HtmlEditorExtender
    TargetControlID="txtComments"
    runat="server" />
```

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Yes i can, but i am not available to that now. I left my notebook at the office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the property :

```
DisplaySourceTab="True"
```

to your htmleditorextender  ? (default is false)

In the code there is an error :

```
... runat="server"/>
```

should be

```
runat="server">
```

Comment: Yep i did. I can show my code after 5 hours. My laptop is not near me. The only difference from this www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx tutorial i have a master page. Others are same. I used vs2012 default template.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding the following line into my code:

```
<ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1" />
```

I was originally using

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

but by replacing it with the above code, the toolbar appeared and I have, so far, not had any adverse affects.

Hope this helps.